# LIDAR Lite giving random address

Tags: i2c, pi-2

I am using LIDAR Lite module ([website](http://pulsedlight3d.com/)) to calculate the distance and it uses I2C connection. I connect the pins out of the LIDAR into a level shifter since RPi accepts 3.3V. When I run the command `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`, almost all addresses are shown and they change every time I run the command again. The address of the LIDAR should be ***0x62***, but instead I am getting many addresses. I have tested the module on Arduino Uno and it works fine. I am using (RPi 2 model B 2014).

The help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What doed i2cdetect -y 1 show if you have nothing connected to the expansion header?

Comment: By the expansion header, do you mean the level shifter? If so, it shows nothing

Comment: The expansion header is the row of 26 or 40 pins (depending on the model) on the side of the Pi.  I'm not sure which model you have as the Pi2 only came out in 2015.

Comment: ohh. I have the latest one and it has 40pins and it shows nothing when I run i2cdetect

Comment: By nothing I'm going to assume you mean a blank grid is displayed when nothing is connected to the 40 pins.  It sounds like your wiring is wrong when you connect the device.  Precisely what have you connected between the Pi and the I2C device?  A photo might be useful.

Comment: The 4 main connections SDA,SCL, Vcc and GND. this is not the first time using i2c communication on the RPi where I have tested other chips and they work seamlessly.

Comment: You mentioned a level shifter.  That probably should not be used.  Your I2C device should not have pull-ups fitted.  The only pull-ups should be the Pis hard-wired ones to 3V3 on SDA/SCL.  If that's the case a level shifter is not needed.

Comment: But the voltage of the SDA and SCL is 5V (measured) and that will probably damage the RPi and that's why I'm down shifting the voltage from 5 to 3.3V. Can I connect it directly even though it outputs 5V?

Comment: The LIDAR should not have pull-ups fitted.  I assume the LIDAR is pulling SDA/SCL to 5V.  If you can't disable them then you have no choice but to use a level shifter, but I suspect the level shifter is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your level-shifter is the problem. The LIDAR lite I2C uses 3.3V logic. (The 5V line feeds a regulator inside the unit.) The external trigger pin also uses 3.3v logic.

See their documentation here-

http://kb.pulsedlight3d.com/support/solutions/articles/5000550871-what-voltage-can-the-lidar-lite-pins-handle-

Comment: so I'll connect the sensor directly and it won't burn?

Comment: Gald to help! They are great sensors!